# How to apply 'text-overflow:ellipsis' subject with badge text on right?

Tags: html, css

I tried to make a fixed-width line which contains book title and badge text,
which shortens the title and add ellipsis when length of title and badge text is too long.

When the badge is on the left of the title, it can be easily done with
`overflow:hidden` + `text-overflow:ellipsis`. for example,

```
| [Sold Out] The Stackoverflow Book                    |
| [Sold Out] the quick brown fox jumps over the laz... |
| [Pre-Order Now] the quick brown fox jumps over th... |
| [Only 3 left in stock] the quick brown fox jumps ... |
```

it worked well with `overflow:hidden` + `text-overflow:ellipsis`.
But I coudln't figure out how to achieve the same result
when the badge text is on the right. for example,

```
| The Stackoverflow Book [Sold Out]                    |
| the quick brown fox jumps over the laz... [Sold Out] |
| the quick brown fox jumps over th... [Pre-Order Now] |
| the quick brown fox jumps ... [Only 3 left in stock] |
```

How can I achiveve proper ellipsis display with badge text on right?
(badge must show all the text they have)

Comment: Can you please add a working version of your code with issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `display: flex` with `margin-left: auto` for the badge.

HTML:

```
<div class=line>
<div class=subject>
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
</div>
<div class=badge>
[Sold Out]</div>
</div>

<div class=line>
<div class=subject>
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
</div>
<div class=badge>
[Pre-Order Now]
</div>
</div>
<div class=line>
<div class=subject>
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
</div>
<div class=badge>
[Only 3 left in stock]
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.line {
  display: flex;
}
.subject {
    white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.push {
  margin-left: auto;
}
.badge {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/ftbLph2m/3/

Comment: That was exactly what i wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using `flex` this should turn out fairly easy.

```css
.book {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
}

.title {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.status {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<p class="book">
  <span class="title">the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</span>
  <span class="status">[Sold Out]</span>
</p>

<p class="book">
  <span class="title">the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</span>
  <span class="status">[Pre-Order Now]</span>
</p>

<p class="book">
  <span class="title">the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</span>
  <span class="status">[Only 3 left in stock]</span>
</p>
```